# How to resize UIImage created with resizableImageWithCapInsets when used for an UIImageView / UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm writing code to use a custom image as the background for a `UIView`.

The app runs in portrait only. Prior to the 4" retina screen, I used fixed size, hand-drawn png as the background image (`card.png` below). I had code like this:

```
UIView* frontView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
frontView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

UIImage* cardImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card.png"];
UIImageView* im = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cardImage];
im.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[frontView addSubview:im];

// frontView has a bunch of stuff added...
```

As you'd expect, when I run this on an iPhone 5, everything can be dynamically sized and positioned, except for the hand drawn png, `card.png`. So that background image isn't using the full height that is available...

So what (I think) I want to do, is something like this...

```
UIImage* cardImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"card_resizable.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(72, 0, 60, 0)];
```

I've redrawn `card.png` as `card_resizable.png` - it's 140 pixels in height, there's an 8 pixel chunk in the middle, which I want to tile, so the top inset is 72 pixels tall and the bottom inset is 60 pixels tall.

What's the next step?

Should I create the `UIImageView` with the dynamic size of `frontView`?

How do I make the resizable image, resize?

The few things that I've tried... none of them have resulted in tiling the resizable image.

Cheers,
Gavin

**Update:**

I was incorrectly setting the pixel values for `UIEdgeInsetsMake(72, 0, 60, 0)`
These values are based on the `@2x` image. When changed to `UIEdgeInsetsMake(36, 0, 30, 0)` - I get the correct, vertical resizing.

As Mike pointed out, I needed to set the size of the `UIImageView` to the parent, and correctly set it's `autoresizingMask`:

`im.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

I know have the `UIImageView` sized dynamically sized, correctly, to fill its parent view - `frontView` (I've given it a green background to check visually on both 3.5" screen and 4" screen.

The resizable image, `cardImage`, is also resizing, correctly, in the vertical plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've passed the stretchable image to a `UIImageView` you just resize that image view to whatever height you need.

In your case, you probably want to make the image view fill its parent by doing this:

```
im.frame = frontView.bounds;
im.autoresizingMask =
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[frontView addSubview:im];
```

We make `im` fill the `frontView` and tell it to automatically increase its width/height when its parent (`frontView`) changes size. This should do what you want.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for pointing those to things out: setting the bounds and the autoresizing mask. I had tried setting the bounds and was using a resizing mask... But the wrong resizing mask, I needed `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` as you've pointed out. As it happens, the real problem was with my cap insets... The values of 72 and 60 were based on the `@2x` image (no way of you guys knowing that)... when I put then in 1x space, I got the vertical resizing desired (with the correct `autoresizingMask` in place.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with stretchableImage

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card_resizable.png"];
UIImage* cardImage = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0f 
                                                topCapHeight:70.0f];
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I tried `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` - but it's not what I need. `resizableImageWithCapInsets` is correct; I was making other mistakes. Cheers.

Comment: @GavinHope Good to hear that :)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at UIView contentMode property. it should give you some sense about how the UIImageView render the image inside, whenever it change it's size.